# Hello World with Arduino Leonardo

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, usb

I have a Arduino `Leonardo` board. and i get an error : `avrdude: stk500_getsync(): not in sync:  resp: resp=0X54`

I have downloaded the Arduino environment [from here](http://arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoLeonardo). I am on my Mac.

I selected the Arduino Board as Arduino UNO, and the serial Port as `/dev/tty.usbmodemfd121` and when i click on the upload button i get the error message `avrdude: stk500_getsync(): not in sync:  resp: resp=0X54`.

When I click on the reset button, and click on Upload, I get a popup window that says `Serial port /dev/tty.usbmodemfd121 not found. Retry the upload with another serial port`.

and in the list of serial ports, i have

```
/dev/tty.Bluetooth-Modem
/dev/cu.Bluetooth-modem
/dev/tty.iphone-wirelessiAP
/dev/cu.iphone-wirelessiAP
/dev/tty.Bluetooth-PDA-Sync
/dev/cu.Bluetooth-PDA-Sync
```

What should i do to run my Hello World code ?

**UPDATE**

```
Binary sketch size: 4,858 bytes (of a 28,672 byte maximum)
Found programmer: Id = "B¯˜"; type = 
 Software Version = 
avrdude: error: buffered memory access not supported. Maybe it isn't a butterfly/AVR109 but a AVR910 device?
```

Comment: Why are you selecting Arduino UNO when you are using a Leonardo? The third sentence in the link you provided states, "you must choose Arduino Leonardo from the Tools > Board menu in the Arduino IDE"

Comment: There is no Arduino Leonardo in the > Tools.

Comment: Which version of the IDE do you have? You need 1.0.1 for it to work properly with the Leonardo. See [here](http://www.arduino.cc/forum/index.php?topic=106659.0) Reply #6 in particular. But read the whole thread as it seems similar to your problem.

Comment: Yes, Thank you for that, i missed it. But, i am unable to upload the Blink code to the board. It says `Uploading...` nearly for 3 mins, and then printed an error message which i have added it as an Update in the post above.

Comment: Did you try reburning the firmware as talked about in Reply #3 in the above link? Or are you by chance using a USB 3.0 port as was the problem [here](http://forums.adafruit.com/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=31662)?

Comment: Done. Please add a comment to let future visitors know which item solved your problem (i.e. the reburning of the firmware or the USB 3.0 issue). Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things to check:

1. Are you running version 1.0.1 of the IDE? It is required to interface to the Leonardo. See Reply #6 from [this thread](http://www.arduino.cc/forum/index.php?topic=106659.0) in the Arduino forum.
2. Have you reburned the firmware for the Leonardo? See Reply #3 from the above mentioned thread.
3. Are you using a USB 3.0 interface? If so, using a USB 2.0 cable in a USB 3.0 interface has been known to cause issues. See [this thread](http://forums.adafruit.com/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=31662) from Adafruit.